# Calling jpegoptim and pngquant from java Process, passing image in stdin and reading result in stdout: broken pipe or hang

Tags: java, bash, image-processing

I have an imagen in a variable of type jpeg or png and i am triying to convert it with command line jpegoptim or pngquant via java 1.6.

The problem is that i cannot make it work. I read a lot of answer but i did not find the answer.

this is the last function i tried:

```
public int execute(byte[] image) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commandLine);
    final Process process = processBuilder.start();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream outputBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream errorBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        // Handle stdout...
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    IOUtils.copy(process.getInputStream(), outputBuffer);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("Error executing " + commandLine,e);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        // Handle sderr...
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    IOUtils.copy(process.getErrorStream(), errorBuffer);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("Error executing " + commandLine,e);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        process.getOutputStream().write(image);
        process.getOutputStream().flush();
        process.waitFor();

        result = outputBuffer.toByteArray();
        errorMsg = errorBuffer.toString("ASCII");

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOG.error("Error executing " + commandLine,e);
    } finally {
        if( process != null ) {
            close(process.getErrorStream());
            close(process.getOutputStream());
            close(process.getInputStream());
            process.destroy();
        }
    }
    return process.exitValue();
}
```

and commandline is for jpg:

```
this.commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
this.commandLine.add("jpegoptim");
this.commandLine.add("-m90");
this.commandLine.add("--stdout");
this.commandLine.add("--stdin");
```

and for png:

```
this.commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
this.commandLine.add("pngquant");
this.commandLine.add("--quality=70-80");
this.commandLine.add(">stdout");
this.commandLine.add("<stdin");
```

The problem with this code is broken pipe. I tried different ways of code. I read different forum here but I dont know how to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

As LinuxDisciple suggested I changed the command to:

```
        List<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        commandLine.add("tee");
        commandLine.add("-a"); 
        commandLine.add("logfile.log");
```

And the code to:

```
    byte[] image = jpg.read(args[0]); // path to file...
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commandLine);

    final Process process = processBuilder.start();

    OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
    final InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
    final InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();

    Thread errorT = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            try {
                while ((len = stdout.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    // process byte buffer
                    System.out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    System.out.flush();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    errorT.start();

    Thread outputT = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            try {
                while ((len = stderr.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    System.err.write(buf, 0, len);
                    System.err.flush();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    outputT.start();

    stdin.write(image);
    stdin.flush();
    //stdin.close();

    try {
        process.waitFor();

    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    stdin.close();
    stderr.close();
    stdout.close();
```

The waitfor never returns... what is missing?

If I put "stdin.close();" after the flush (in the code above is commented) the process ends. but the stdout is not fully processed and an error is shown: java.io.IOException: Stream closed twice (one for each thread). The logfile.log is equal to the image, but the stdout is truncated.

I test this by command line:

java -cp testProc.jar testProc.Test image.jpg > image_new.jpg

logfile.log is equal to image.jpg
image_new.jpg is smaller and a truncated version of image.jpg.

some clue?

Answer (score 0):

Start with your last two lines. You don't pass `stdin` using `>stdin`. Look for some ProcessBuilder examples to see how to use a BufferedWriter to write to the process's stdin (your Java process's stdout), then do the same for your subprocess' stdout with a BufferedReader.
If you still have issues after that, then for diagnosis, you could try replacing `jpegoptim` and `pngquant` with `tee -a logfile`, which will take stdin and just pipe it right back to stdout (and to a file called logfile).
 Then you've got a file that has all the piped-in data, or you'll get an empty file and the pipe error because your Java program isn't passing in the data and you can see if it looks right.
 If instead you get a file with data and you don't get a pipe error, it probably means `jpegoptim` isn't returning any data.
 At that point you could pipe the data from `logfile` into `jpegoptim` on the command line and play with the options until you get it working, and then use those working options in your Java code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer LinuxDisciple. I made what you suggested but now I have others errors. I edited the post to show them

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it work!

I found the solution by pure fortune!...
I discommented the line:

```
stdin.close();
```

And added just after the line "process.waitFor();": this lines:

```
errorT.join();
outputT.join();
```

To process the images the commands are:

```
commandLine.add("jpegoptim");
commandLine.add("-m90");
commandLine.add("--stdout");
commandLine.add("--stdin");
```

and:

```
commandLine.add("pngquant");
commandLine.add("--quality=70-80");
commandLine.add("-");
```

The final code:

```
public int execute(List<String> commandLine, byte[] image) throws IOException {

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commandLine);

    final Process process = processBuilder.start();

    OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
    final InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
    final InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();


    final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Thread errorT = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            try {
                while ((len = stdout.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    // process byte buffer
                    bos.write(buf, 0, len);
                    bos.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    errorT.start();

    Thread outputT = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            try {
                while ((len = stderr.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    System.err.write(buf, 0, len);
                    System.err.flush();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    outputT.start();

    stdin.write(image);
    stdin.flush();

    stdin.close();

    try {
        process.waitFor();

        errorT.join();
        outputT.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    stdin.close();
    stderr.close();
    stdout.close();


    System.out.write(bos.toByteArray());

    return 0;
}
```